# Remove or disable all MSI Installation UI

Tags: user-interface, windows-installer

I want make my MSI installer to display nothing when I double click on it. Currently it displays the simple default progress bar during installation. I don't even want that to display. Is there any work around for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, Windows Installer will show a basic UI if you don't provide one. Some form of feedback is required, else how would the user know they successfully launched the package?